# Treeview consistency check(s)

Tags: c#, tree, treeview, consistency

I have a GUI with TreeViewAdv and some data in a ListBox which can be dragged and dropped onto nodes in the tree to create a hierarchy. Users can also define new nodes. The tree is manipulated in memory but can be committed to the backend by the user. Each node is saved as an object with relations to other objects.

The question is are there some good ideas on how to run consistency checks on the tree when the user drags and drops new nodes. Consistency checks like: has it been added to another node before.

I thought of some options which needs to cover previous manipulation (saved in database) and current manipulation:

1) Run it in memory, unfortunately in order to have complete overview this would mean to expand/collapse the entire tree at least once in order to initialize the nodes, but also some smaller database round trips when initializing some of the nodes.

2) Use the current initialized GUI nodes and also run a check against the database as all previous relations are saved, but this will have larger overhead in database round trips.

3) Read in the current database configuration during GUI initialization and cache what is needed to run consistency checks. Then use this and the current tree. This should result in a better user experience I think.

Any other ideas?

Thank you.